# File Stream failing on read after seeking to end of file

Tags: c++, file-io, filestream

I need to read the last 64kb from a large file, but after seeking to the end of the file, then back 64kb, all reads on the file fail.

Here's a snippet:

```
string filename = "test.txt";
ifstream::streampos pos; // used to keep track of position in file
ifstream fs;

fs.open(filename, ios::binary);
fs.seekg(0, ios::end);
pos = fs.tellg();

// ....

fs.seekg(-16, ios::cur);

char buff[16];

fs.read(buff, 16);

// ...

fs.close();
```

The problem is on `fs.read()` the `eofbit`, `failbit`, and `badbit` are set and the file stream becomes unusable. It is worth noting that the file I'm reading from is being continuously appended to. Also, sometimes this approach works and sometimes it doesn't, which makes debugging difficult.

Is there any reason why this would be happening?

Comment: Shouldn't `fs.seekg(-16, ios::end);` work?

Comment: The `// ...` are a bit too obscure. Can you provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces this behavior with some simple input example please?

Comment: That doesn't really fit my needs though because I need to read the file in chunks starting from the end. So I need to read the last 16b, then the second to last 16b and so on. 16b is arbitrary though.

Comment: Also you can simply call `fs.clear()` after `fs.read()` to get rid of the `eofbit`, `failbit`, and `badbit`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you call `tellg` after seeking the end of file. `tellg` causes the pointer to advance invoking the eof state on the stream: Here is the issue:

```
fs.open(filename, ios::binary);
fs.seekg(0, ios::end);
pos = fs.tellg();   // <== causes eof on stream
```

Your next call to `fs.seekg` should clear the eof state, but it is probably better to call `fs.clear()` and check the return to insure it succeeds.

Comment: I tried this but tellg worked fine and gave the correct position.

Comment: Yes, `tellg()` does work fine, but **it advances the file position counter**. If you just used `seek()` to move to the end of file and then call `tellg()` you have advanced the counter beyond the end setting `eof` on the stream. It is just like moving to the end and then trying to read the next character.